# Approximating Binomial with Normal

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider approximating a binomial distribution with normal. Originally, my binomial distribution is discrete, where the heights of the bars represent the probability. However, after approximating this distribution with a normal one, we find the probabilities using the area beneath the normal curve. How have the probabilities just changed from being heights to area? It seems unintuitive how these probabilities are more or less the same.

Comment: Rectangles have area too

Answer (score 0):

It is an approximation, and only works reasonably well in some cases.

Let's take an example where it works well if you approach it sensibly, where $X$ is a binomial random variable with $n=48$ and $p=\frac14$,
so with mean $12$ and standard deviation $3$, and $Y$ is a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation.

Suppose we want to approximate $P(X \le 10)$. This is also $P(X \lt 11)$ because of $X$ only taking integer values so it is not obvious where to look on the distribution of $Y$, but it might be sensible to consider $P(Y \le 10.5)=P(Y \lt 10.5)$ and this is about $0.309$.  In fact $P(X \le 10) \approx 0.316$, so a reasonably close approximation if not exact.

We can extend this to looking at $P(X=10)$ and a reasonable approximation might be about $P(Y \le 10.5)-P(Y \le 9.5) \approx 0.106$ when the exact figure is $P(X=10)={48 \choose 10}\frac{3^{38}}{4^{48}} \approx 0.112$, again reasonably close though not exact.

You can say $P(X=10) = P(X \le 10.5)-P(X \le 9.5)$ and so $P(Y \le 10.5)-P(Y \le 9.5)$ looks more reasonable as an approximation in this context.

$P(Y \le 10.5)-P(Y \le 9.5)$ is the probability represented by the area over an interval, while $P(X \le 10.5)-P(X \le 9.5)$ is the probability of the point $10$ in the middle of the interval, but in terms of cumulative distribution functions there is not much practical distinction from this point of view.

(Another possible approximation to $P(X=10)$ is the density of $Y$ at $10$ and this is also about $0.106$, but this can be seen as an approximation of the average density across the interval of width $1$ and so to the area, and is not really relevant to your question.)